# how to combine mp3 file with mp4 file in android

Tags: android, frame-grab

I am creating app that was change the audio of video file in android.
I tried the code below. Appreciate your help.

```
try {
    FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
    FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(audioPath);
    grabber1.start();
    grabber2.start();
    FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(OutputPath,
            grabber1.getImageWidth(), grabber1.getImageHeight(), 2);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setVideoQuality(1);
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber1.getFrameRate());
    recorder.setSampleRate(grabber2.getSampleRate());
    recorder.start();
    Frame frame1, frame2 = null;
    long timestamp = -2;
    int count = 0;
    boolean isFirstTime = false;
    boolean isFirstCheck = true;
    while ((frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame())!=null) {
        //frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame();
        frame2 = grabber2.grabFrame();
        recorder.record(frame1);
        recorder.record(frame2);

    }
    recorder.stop();
    grabber1.stop();
    grabber2.stop();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: you have to explain properly. as like post reference link you have used with post proper code you have used..

Answer (score 0):

you can look into **exoplayer** which allows you to customise the audio input stream and video input stream. its open source by google and apps like you-tube and google play movies use it.